# Unable to post JSON to local host with curl

Tags: json, curl, localhost

I am trying to pass `{"BPM": 456}` to my localhost:8080.

When I try it with Postman it mseems to work fine.

On the other hand, when I try it with the following curl command, it doesnt seem to work.

```
curl  -d {"BPM":456} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X  POST http://localhost:8080/
```

It doesnt work, I will appreciate any guidance with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some funny reason, using the syntax below did not work.

`curl  -d {"BPM":456} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X  POST http://localhost:8080/`

I had to use pass the call in this format:

`curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"BPM":456}' \
  http://localhost:8080`

Comment: It's likely the `-d` / `--data`; `bash` may be stripping off the braces or doing something else with the value when it's not quoted.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check the port 8080. Or if you using a Virtual Host in localhost. Check the host and port configuration again. 
I tried your commend using my localhost ,It works.